# Deploying VPN connection with routing rules on OS X

Tags: macos, vpn, azure, macos-mojave, macos-highsierra

I work in an organisation with a mix of PC and Mac, we have an Azure environment with two connections (prod and nonprod)

On the PC side, I can create a package that will install a VPN complete with all of the routing rules required to access each environment. This allows me to send out two VPN packages that configures everything. They put a username / password in and it connects.

I would like to replicate this on OS X, is it possible to programatically create a VPN connection on OS X complete with the required routes for each connection.

The connection is an IKEv2 IPSEC